# Summary statistics with grouping by multiple columns dataframe vs. data.table vs. dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, summarize

I'm working my way through the Titanic Study in Frank Harrell's R Flow course (http://hbiostat.org/rflow/case.html) and have a question about summarizing data. The raw data (Titanic5.csv) can be downloaded from https://hbiostat.org/data/repo/titanic5.csv He uses data.table (d is a data.table) to summarize the dataset as follows:

```
# Create a function that drops NAs when computing the mean
# Note that the mean of a 0/1 variable is the proportion of 1s
mn <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
# Create a function that counts the number of non-NA values
Nna <- function(x) sum(! is.na(x))
# This is for generality; there are no NAs in these examples
d[, .(Proportion=mn(survived), N=Nna(survived)), by=sex]    # .N= # obs in by group
```

The result of the last command is:

```
      sex Proportion   N
1: female  0.7274678 466
2:   male  0.1909846 843
```

Even more interesting is

```
d[, .(Proportion=mn(survived), N=Nna(survived)), by=.(sex,class)]
```

which gives

```
      sex class Proportion   N
1: female     1  0.9652778 144
2:   male     1  0.3444444 180
3:   male     2  0.1411765 170
4: female     2  0.8867925 106
5:   male     3  0.1521298 493
6: female     3  0.4907407 216
```

The results are exactly what I want,but the syntax depends very strongly on the capabilities of data.table. How can I get the same results using a dataframe instead of a data table, ideallly with base R, but also with dplyr?

Sincerely

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2):

- With `base R`

```
aggregate(Survived ~ Sex , d ,
          \(x) c(Proportion = mean(x) , N = length(x)))

aggregate(Survived ~ Sex + Class, d , 
          \(x) c(Proportion = mean(x) , N = length(x)))
```

- Output

```
#> first

    Sex Survived.Proportion  Survived.N
1 female           0.7274678    466
2   male           0.1909846    843

#> second

    Sex Class Survived.Proportion  Survived.N
1 female     1           0.9652778   144
2   male     1           0.3444444   180
3 female     2           0.8867925   106
4   male     2           0.1411765   170
5 female     3           0.4907407   216
6   male     3           0.1521298   493
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm teaching myself R and it's often striking how one way is much easier than another way, and how different the syntax can be for seemingly similar tasks. I was also unaware of the stats package - I will look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning `dplyr`, the most straight-forward way for achieving this would probably be the usual combination of `group_by()` and `summarize()`. Summarizing the data by `Sex` and `Class` may be done in the following way:

```
d %>%  
  group_by(Sex, Class) %>% 
  summarize(
    Proportion = mn(Survived), 
    N = Nna(Survived)
  )

# Output
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Sex'. You can
override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   Sex [2]
  Sex    Class Proportion     N
  <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl> <int>
1 female     1      0.965   144
2 female     2      0.887   106
3 female     3      0.491   216
4 male       1      0.344   180
5 male       2      0.141   170
6 male       3      0.152   493
```

And just summarizing by `Sex`:

```
d %>%  
  group_by(Sex) %>% 
  summarize(
    Proportion = mn(Survived), 
    N = Nna(Survived)
  )

# Output
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Sex    Proportion     N
  <chr>       <dbl> <int>
1 female      0.727   466
2 male        0.191   843
```

Finally, here also a solutions using `stats` which I assume is close enough to "base R"(?). It's not the most elegant solution, i.e. maybe one can immediately assign the variables with respective variable names and functions, but it works well:

```
summary_mn <- stats::aggregate(Survived ~ Sex + Class, data = as.data.frame(d), FUN = function(x) mn(x))
summary_nna <- stats::aggregate(Survived ~ Sex + Class, data = as.data.frame(d), FUN = function(x) Nna(x))

summary_full <- merge(summary_mn, summary_nna, by = c("Sex", "Class"))
colnames(summary_full) <- c("Sex", "Class", "Proportion", "N")

summary_full

# Output
     Sex Class Proportion   N
1 female     1  0.9652778 144
2 female     2  0.8867925 106
3 female     3  0.4907407 216
4   male     1  0.3444444 180
5   male     2  0.1411765 170
6   male     3  0.1521298 493
```

Comment: You may not need a merge but a cbind here, isn't it?

Comment: @jangorecki Either of them works. However, if I were to use the base R solution I would assign the variables immediately with a named vector as suggested in the other answer.